# Essential extension and injective hull of a simple module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, injective-module

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $N$ be a simple $R$-module (that is, isomorphic to $R/m$ for some maximal ideal $m$ of $R$). I guess that the following statement is true, but I can't prove or disprove it. Can anyone help me?

> $M$ is an essential extension of $N$ if and only if $M$ is a submodule of $E(N)$, where $E(N)$ is the injective hull of $N$.

Comment: How have you seen $E(N)$ constructed? It is very often explained as a maximal essential extension of $N$, which would make this follow almost from definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is an essential extension of $N$ and consider the injective hull $E(N)$ of $N$. Denote by $f\colon N\to M$ an injective homomorphism and by $i\colon N\to E(N)$ the embedding in the injective hull.

By definition of injective module, there exists $g\colon M\to E(N)$ such that $gf=i$. Since
$$
\ker g\cap f(N)=\{0\}
$$
and $f(N)$ is essential in $M$ (by assumption), we conclude $\ker g=\{0\}$, so $g$ is an embedding.

<sub>It's an abuse of language saying that $M$ is a submodule of $E(N)$; what you can say is that $M$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $E(N)$.</sub>

The converse is obvious: if $N\subseteq M\subseteq E(N)$, $N$ is essential in $E(N)$ and so also in $M$.

Note that the simplicity of $N$ has not been used. Indeed, the result holds for *every* $R$-module $N$. The key fact is that $E(N)$ is an essential extension of $N$.